# ASP page Error - 0x80004005 When trying to get Request("variable")

Tags: asp.net, post, asp-classic, request

I am trying to read a post variable  and I get this error:

```
0x80004005 - unknown exception
```

The line causing it:

```
request("total"))
```

I read something about permissions may be causing it, tried to implement, but it is still happening.

UPDATE:(added full code)

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form4" name="form4" action="url" method="post">
    <%
        total=request("total")
     %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your post data's length, if too large , then 'unknown exception' occurs.

FYR: http://www.bigresource.com/ASP-Max-Char-Length-of-POST-variable-8cxQFVTf.html